# How do I install wireless drivers in a virtual machine running Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, internet, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a virtual machine, Wi-Fi isn't working, and I can't find Broadcom drivers.

This is what is shown when I go to Additional Drivers:

[image: Screenshot of the Additional Drivers tab of Software & Updates]

Comment: You do not need to install any drivers to a virtual machine. It does not have access to hardware.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Virtual machines use virtual network cards so it is unlikely your boradcam card has any relevance. We need more details including what virtualization technology.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Obviously, it is VirtualBox.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Thanks the OP added in that information AFTER I posted my comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you wont use WiFi from the virtual machine / guest OS. Instead set up NAT or Bridge network to the host OS and let that handle WiFi.